# Finding and replacing lines that begin with a pattern

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a text in a file file.txt like this

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
a    b   c // delimited by tab
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I know using `sed` I can find and replace text in a file. If a line starts with a   b(seperated by a tab) I need to replace it with d   e   f. So the above file will be

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
d    e   f // delimited by tab
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I can do this to find and replace, I want only those instances where the line starts with a   b and replace the whole line.

```
sed -i 's/a/\t/\b/\t\/c/REPLACED TEXT/g' file.TXT
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a `^` symbol to represent the beginning of a line:

`sed -i 's/^a\tb.*$/REPLACED TEXT/g' file.TXT`

Exmplanation:

- `^` means *beginning of line/input*
- `\t` means *tab symbol*
- `.` means *any character*
- `*` means *zero or more of the preceeding expression*
- `$` means *end of line/input*

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace the entire line if it begins with `a<tab>b<tab>c`.  The `.*$` makes the match include the entire line for replacement. Your example regex included `c` but the prose only mentioned `a` and `b`, so it wasn't quite clear if `c` is required.  If not, then remove `\tc` from the regex.

```
s/^a\tb\tc.*$/REPLACED TEXT/g
```

Comment: yes we can remove \tc .. The line only have to start with a and b

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
awk '/^a\tb/{$0="REPLACED TEXT"} 1' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^a\tb/c\replacement text' file
```