# Batch Script - trying to replace a text string in all files of a specific extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd, find

I am trying to change all *.gpx files in a directory, editing out all instances of "Flag, Blue" with "Waypoint" (without quotation marks). I'm not great at Windows script and so want a little help debugging.

I have based this code on code by in question:

[Batch Script - Find and replace text in multiple files in a directory without asking user to install any program or add other files to my batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467475/batch-script-find-and-replace-text-in-multiple-files-in-a-directory-without-as)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // based on code by aschipfl
rem // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467475/batch-script-find-and-replace-text-in-multiple-files-in-a-directory-without-as

rem // Define constants here:

set "_MASK=*.gpx"        & rem // (working on all GPX files)
set "_SEARCH=Flag, Blue" & rem // (find those HORRIBLE blue flags)
set "_REPLAC=Waypoint"   & rem // (repace with WAYPOINTS)
set "FOROPT="            & rem // NON-recursive
set "IFSW="              & rem // CaSe sEnSiTiVe YeS

set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)
pushd "." || exit /B 1

rem // Loop through all matching files in the directory tree:
for %FOROPT% %%F in ("%_MASK%") do (
    rem // Write to temporary file:
    > "%_TMPF%" (
        rem /* Read current file line by line; use `findstr` to precede every line by
        rem    its line number and a colon `:`; this way empty lines appear non-empty
        rem    to `for /F`, which avoids them to be ignored; otherwise empty lines
        rem    became lost: */
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%%~fF"') do (
            rem // Store current line text:
            set "LINE=%%L" & set "FLAG="
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Remove line number prefix:
            set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
            rem // Skip replacement for empty line text:
            if defined LINE (
                rem /* Use `for /F` loop to avoid trouble in case search or replace
                rem    strings contain quotation marks `"`: */
                for /F "tokens=1* delims== eol==" %%I in ("!_SEARCH!=!_REPLAC!") do (
                    rem // Query to handle case-sensitivity:
                    if %IFSW% "!LINE!"=="!LINE:%%I=%%I!" (
                        rem // Detect whether replacement changes line:
                        if not "!LINE!"=="!LINE:%%I=%%J!" (
                            rem // Actually do the sub-string replacement:
                            set "LINE=!LINE:%%I=%%J!"
                            set "FLAG=#"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            rem // Output the resulting line text:
            echo(!LINE!
            if defined FLAG (endlocal & set "FLAG=#") else (endlocal)
        )
    )
    rem // Check whether file content would change upon replacement:
    if defined FLAG (
        rem // Move the temporary file onto the original one:
        > nul move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%%~fF"
    ) else (
        rem // Simply delete temporary file:
        del "%_TMPF%"
    )
)
popd

endlocal
exit /B
```

I run the script but no changes to the GPX files.

A real-world example segment from the GPX file would be:

```
  <ele>1.19734255318821</ele>
  <time>2019-07-28T00:42:12Z</time>
  <name>CW1002</name>
  <sym>Flag, Blue</sym>
  <extensions>
    <trp:ViaPoint>
```

Obviously I want this to remain the same except:

```
  <sym>Waypoint</sym>
```

Comment: Change the line `set "LINE=%%L" & set "FLAG="` to `set "LINE=%%L"` and put `set "FLAG="` as a separate line before `for /F "delims=" %%L ...`; this seems to be a flaw of the original script already...

Comment: I corrected the original code in the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469094) meanwhile...

Comment: Since the issue is now handled [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469094) let me suggest to delete this question...

Comment: Thank you aschipfl and this works perfectly. But I have another problem with it, would you please help before I delete the question? (I can't figure out if./how to PM). Though the file is now fixed it won't import correctly because it has the same name as the program being imported into. I don't mean file name. I mean a line like this: **<name>LL&amp;C Way 1: Portavadie to Tighnabruaich</name>** however after that are many subsequent other **<name></name>** tags. How in the same file could the FIRST instance of **</name>** be changed to **fixed </name>**?

Comment: What about using the search string `<name>LL&amp;C Way 1: Portavadie to Tighnabruaich</name>` and the replace string `<name>LL&amp;C Way 1: Portavadie to Tighnabruaich fixed</name>`?

Comment: How many times will we rewrite `sed`?

Comment: aschipfl thanks for the reply - because the text between the <name></name> varies, and it's not the ONLY use of name in the file. It's the FIRST use of <name>. However I have fixed that, by creating a FIRST flag and a recreation of your replacement test, hardcoding a look for </name>. And that brings me to the next problem. Sometimes <sym>Flag, Blue</sym> isn't in the file so there is nothing to replace, but the program defaults to the Blue Flags. So I'm trying to make it an IF ELSE situation.

Comment: lit - as far as I can tell SED is a compiled program and not available on every PC. This BAT file will be for sharing among the hiking & geocaching communities and it won't get half as much use if it has "download & install programs" requirements.